# How does npm package generate cmd line file

Tags: node.js, batch-file, cmd

When we install Bower or Grunt via npm, we can use the bower or grunt command line tool. Looking inside, it seems to have generated a .cmd file for Windows and (probably, because I haven't looked into it) a .bach file for Unix based system.

I looked at the source code in Github, but haven't got a clue. How does those npm projects generate the cmd batch file which supports both kind of OSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this repo ?

https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/cmd-shim

Comment: It seems to be. I played with that for a while now. Still not sure of two issues: 1. How can I auto-run this during npm install. 2. cmdShim(__dirname + '/cli.js', ... In this, .js is not an executable file. Node xxx.js is. But I don't know how to handle it here.

Comment: ??? Have you read the [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) ? I did not understand q2, because the command is : `"%~dp0\node.exe" "%~dp0\.\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*`